# How do I remap Shift + Del on Windows to mean Delete instead of Cut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-server-2008

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on my Windows computer is interpreted as cut to the clipboard. How can I make it no different than just Delete alone?

Comment: Odd, shift-del on normal windows computers is _supposed_ to mean delete permanently (skip the recycle bin).

Comment: Not in Windows 7 (and similar versions). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Desktop_shortcuts

Comment: In Windows 7 Shift+Del is supposed to be permanent delete. I use it everyday to skip the recycle bin. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449

Comment: Maybe just in Windows Server then? It is listed in other places ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#Common_keyboard_shortcuts ) as meaning cut and that's definitely what it's doing here

Comment: I suspect the OP is talking about in a text or word processor, not Windows Explorer/Desktop.

Comment: the Wikipedia article has the shortcut listed under Desktop Shortcuts though...  Which after doing some searching in Google, is apparently the old legacy behavior.  I have a feeling that it's maybe the result of a Culture/Language setting

Comment: And no, Server 2008 and 2008 R2 don't make a difference, it has to bee something else.  I permanently delete things from Explorer and the desktop all the time using Shift+Del

Comment: It's not just Windows 7.  Shift+Del = Cut, Shift+Ins = Paste, Ctrl+Ins = Copy has been a standard since the DOS days.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste

Comment: In Windows XP `SHIFT+DELETE` on the Destop & in Windows Explorer windows means "Delete the selected item permanently without placing the item in the Recycle Bin" -- see [List of the keyboard shortcuts that are available in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;301583&FR=1&PA=1&SD=HSCH).

Comment: Sure.  Obviously it depends what program you are in.  Shift+Del means Cut in most text editors and text editing fields.

Comment: And as you already acknowledged, the OP wasn't talking about the Desktop or Windows Explorer. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script works for me:

```
+Del::Send {Delete}
```

If it doesn't, try this:

```
+Del::
KeyWait Shift
Send {Delete}
return
```

According to [AutoHotkey Tips and Remarks](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Remarks), you might need to use `KeyWait` so that the <kbd>Shift</kbd> doesn't get applied to the right hand side as well.

I suggest installing it like this:

- [Download](http://www.autohotkey.net/~Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/AutoHotkey_L_Install.exe) and install AutoHotkey, allowing it to associate with `.ahk` files
- Open Notepad and paste the script in
- Save it anywhere and call it `shortcuts.ahk`
- Open the folder where you saved it in Windows Explorer
- Double click on `shortcuts.ahk` to open it and activate it immediately
- Right click and drag `shortcuts.ahk` to Start->(All) Programs->Startup, then release the right button
- Click on Create Shortcut

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of what context you're referring to, and although I haven't done this exact thing, I'm fairly confident the free [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) utility could do it.

At a minimum, the AHK script would just need to be a single line containing this:

```
+Delete::Send {Delete}
```

This would be in effect globally (i.e. on the Desktop, in Explorer windows, and in all applications). If necessary, it could be made context-sensitive so that it only applied to specific situations ([RTFM](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs)).

Comment: I tried, but I don't really know AutoHotKey, what's the code for Shift + Del? I tried +{Delete} but it didn't work

Comment: `+{Delete}` or `+{Del}` represents shift+delete. You could create an AHK script for that combination which just maps it to `Send {Delete}`.

Comment: `+{Del}::Send {Delete}` gave me an error `Invalid hotkey`

Comment: Try `+Del::Send {Delete}` without the `{}` around the first `Del`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the syntactically correct AHK code -- thanks @Mikel.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotkey CAN`T do this.
It is complicated to be explained but AutoHotkey send to focused window so you cant send command to desktop.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.